# How to run hangfire on a specific day in a week

Tags: .net, .net-core, hangfire

I want to run a schedule on thursday 12:00 a.m. every week
how to write the cron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you would want the Cron.Weekly(DayOfWeek, Hour).

The IRecurringJobManager interface has a method for adding or updating your tasks (`AddOrUpdate`). That method contains an argument for specifying a timeframe.

If you're using a startup project, you would add your task like so:

```cs
fooJobManager.AddOrUpdate("TaskName", exampleFunctionToRun, Cron.Weekly(DayOfWeek.Thursday, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the expression that you want: `0 12 */7 * 4`

It is representing `min hour day month day-of-week'.